# How to uninstall the old version of expo and install new version of it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, mobile-website

#### I tried the below command

- npm -g uninstall expo-cli --save

After running the above command if I run `expo --verion` it shows the old version of expo

#### It shows the following error

- found 13 vulnerabilities (9 low, 4 high)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

1.npm cache clean -f

2.yarn upgrade

3.npm upgrade

4.npm install

If this doesn't work try edit package.json:

```
{
  "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-33.0.0.tar.gz",
  "expo": "^33.0.0",
  "react": "16.8.3"
}
```

Then

npm install

let me know if this works for you

Comment: Thanks sir for responding. I did the same you said but shows the same error

Comment: When I run `npm cache clean -f` command it show `npm WARN using --force I sure hope you know what you are doing.`

Comment: use sudo npm cache clean -f

Comment: When I run `sudo npm cahce clean -f` It's printing like this `npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.`